# Javascript: Calculate angle of rectangle with 4 corner points

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, matrix

I have an `matrix` like this:

```
var matrix = [
  "00000000000000000000000",
  "00000000001100000000000",
  "00000000111110000000000",
  "00000001111111000000000",
  "00000111111111100000000",
  "00000111111111000000000",
  "00000011111100000000000",
  "00000001110000000000000",
  "00000000100000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000000"
]
```

...and I know the 4 corner points (x/y-coordinates) of the figure (rectangle of '1'-characters) like..

- [11,1]
- [5,4]
- [14,4]
- [8,8]

[image: matrix image 1]

Is there an easy way to calculate the rotation angle of the rectangle like I've symbolized in this image?

[image: matrix image 2]

Because I have no clue how to continue I can not provide you more code than this:

> Edit: The function above gets the minY and the maxX value from the 4 points. Afterwards the function is calculating the distance between the two points. But now how to calculate the angle?

```js
function calculate_angle(corner_object) {
  Array.prototype.calculate_distance = function() {
    var x1=this[0],y1=this[1],x2=this[2],y2=this[3]
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)).toFixed(2);
  }
  var list = [my_object.corner1,my_object.corner2,my_object.corner3,my_object.corner4]
  var extreme_result = {
    'xMax': list.filter(e => e[0] === Math.max(...list.map(e => e[0]))),
    'yMin': list.filter(e => e[1] === Math.min(...list.map(e => e[1])))
  }
  var distance = [extreme_result.xMax[0][0],extreme_result.xMax[0][1],extreme_result.yMin[0][0],extreme_result.yMin[0][1]].calculate_distance()
  
  // distance between two points is "distance"
  
  console.log(distance)
}


var my_object = {
                  "corner1":[5,4],
                  "corner2":[11,1],
                  "corner3":[14,4],
                  "corner4":[8,8]
                }
calculate_angle(my_object)
```

---

I hope somebody can help me with my code...
 Thanks a lot in advance, jonas

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

I think you can follow this script:

https://codepen.io/pablodarde/pen/aVEmGO

1. Get the position of the highest rectangle base vertex;
2. Get the position of the lower rectangle base vertex;
3. Calc the rectangle opposite Leg: (H) with the above information;
4. Calc the rectangle adjacent leg: (W) with the above information;
5. Calc the hypotenuse (I): `const I = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(H, 2) + Math.pow(W, 2));`
6. Then, you have the angle cosine. `const cosAngle = Math.cos(W/I);`
7. Get the angle value by doing: `const angle = Math.acos(cosAngle);`

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365879/javascript-calculate-angle-of-rectangle-with-4-corner-points/47366425#47366425

const matrix = [
  "00000000000000000000000",
  "00000000001100000000000",
  "00000000111110000000000",
  "00000001111111000000000",
  "00000111111111100000000",
  "00000111111111000000000",
  "00000011111100000000000",
  "00000001110000000000000",
  "00000000100000000000000",
  "00000000000000000000000"
];

function getRectangleLowerBaseVertice(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length -1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i].indexOf('1') !== -1) {
      return {line: i, column: arr[i].indexOf('1')};
    }
  }
}

function getRectangleHigherBaseVertice(arr) {
  let col = 0;
  let previous = 0;
  let line = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].lastIndexOf('1') !== -1) {
      if (arr[i].lastIndexOf('1') > previous) {
        col = arr[i].lastIndexOf('1');
        previous = col;
        line = i;
      }
    }
  }
  return {line: line, column: col};
}

const higherBaseVertex = [
  Number(getRectangleHigherBaseVertice(matrix).line),
  Number(getRectangleHigherBaseVertice(matrix).column),
];

const lowerBaseVertex = [
  Number(getRectangleLowerBaseVertice(matrix).line),
  Number(getRectangleLowerBaseVertice(matrix).column),
];

function toDegrees (angle) {
  return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
}

const oppositeLeg = lowerBaseVertex[0] - higherBaseVertex[0];

const adjacentLeg = Math.abs(lowerBaseVertex[1] - higherBaseVertex[1]);

const hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(oppositeLeg, 2) + Math.pow(adjacentLeg, 2));

const cosAngle = Math.cos(adjacentLeg / hypotenuse);

const angle = toDegrees(Math.acos(cosAngle));

document.getElementById('lower-base-vertex').innerHTML = `lower base vertex, line: ${getRectangleLowerBaseVertice(matrix).line}, column: ${getRectangleLowerBaseVertice(matrix).column}`;

document.getElementById('higher-base-vertex').innerHTML = `higher base vertex, line: ${getRectangleHigherBaseVertice(matrix).line}, column: ${getRectangleHigherBaseVertice(matrix).column}`;

document.getElementById('opposite-leg').innerHTML = `Opposite leg: ${oppositeLeg}`;

document.getElementById('adjacent-leg').innerHTML = `Adjacent leg: ${adjacentLeg}`;

document.getElementById('hypotenuse').innerHTML = `hypotenuse: ${hypotenuse}`;

document.getElementById('cos-angle').innerHTML = `angle cosine: ${cosAngle}`;

document.getElementById('angle').innerHTML = `angle: ${angle}`;
```

```html
<div id="lower-base-vertex"></div>

<div id="higher-base-vertex"></div>

<div id="rectangle-height"></div>

<div id="opposite-leg"></div>

<div id="adjacent-leg"></div>

<div id="hypotenuse"></div>

<div id="cos-angle"></div>

<div id="angle"></div>
```

Comment: Sounds legit but I don't get it why I have to use the highest/lowest rectangle base vertex. That will not be the real width/height I thinks so.. However also no clue how to get the rectangles base vertex... :(

Comment: You are right, actually, the "rectangle height", should be "rectangle opposite leg related to the rectangle base". The "rectangle width" should be the "rectangle adjacent leg related to the base"

Comment: Hey @Jonas0000, I updated the answer with some code. I hope this can help you.